# How to configure jbpm with websphere?

Tags: websphere, jbpm

How to configure jbpm with websphere?

Comment: You are going to need to be more specific on where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions here http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JbpmOnWebsphere . If you have a specific issue, query it on SO